# Is it possible to create uiComponent block programatically?

Tags: magento2, backend, uicomponent

It is required to add custom grid in a new tab in `System -> User roles -> Role`.

I was thinking of uiComponent grid however, when I digged into sources I found that users grid is composed via deprecated `\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended` class which is set as children to parent tab block programatically:

```
/**
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->setChild(
        'userGrid',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\User\Block\Role\Grid\User::class, 'roleUsersGrid')
    );
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

It there a way of programmatically create uiComponent block ?